# Is there a way to do multiple assignment and initialization with block scope?

Tags: javascript, scope

I would like to declare two variables with block scope and initialize them to the same value. It would be nice if the following worked that way but it doesn't...

```
{
  let a = b = "wang";
}
console.log("b:", b);
```

Variable 'a' has block scope but variable 'b' doesn't, it has function scope as if it were declared with a var.

Is there a one line* way of accomplishing this or do I have to do...

```
let a, b;
a = b = "wang";
```

---

* not that I would throw readability under a bus to save a couple of chars you understand, I'm just curious!

Comment: It's not like `var`.  It becomes an implicit global. Do not do this!

Comment: @oriol is's exactly like `var`, so it becomes an implicit global. Do this like James Thorpe do

Comment: @edc65 No, it's not like `var`. `var` declarations do not throw in strict mode. Implicit globals do.

Comment: @Oriol I hope var declarations do not always throw in strict mode. What use case are you thinking of? I tried `var a=b=1` in strict mode and it throws "ReferenceError". Just the same with `let a=b=1`

Comment: @edc65 Yes, that's because both `var a=b=1` and `let a=b=1` only declare `a`. `b` is assigned but not declared. So if it wasn't previously declared somewhere else, it will become a global variable in sloppy mode and will throw in strict mode. That's why this code should be avoided.

Comment: @Oriol I'm glad you agree. So the issue with `var` is just the same as with `let`. That's what i wrote before.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it in a single `let` declaration as follows:

```
{
  let a = "wang", b = a;
}
console.log("b:", b); //undefined or ReferenceError
```

Because both `a` and `b` are declared with `let` inside the braces, they both get block scope.  You have to assign `a` first so that it's been assigned before you assign it to `b` also.

Comment: I feel this is best and optimal way

Comment: Thanks. Probably best to only use that with short expressions for readability's sake.

Answer (score 11):

You can use array [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) to avoid repeating the value:

```js
{
  let [a, b, c, d] = Array(4).fill("wang");
  console.log(a, b, c, d); // "wang", "wang", "wang", "wang"
}
a; // ReferenceError
```

If you don't want to bother about the number of variables and don't want to allocate big arrays, you can also use an immediately invoked generator function expression. For simplicity, it may be a good idea to implement this as a helper function

```js
const repeat = function*(value){while(true) yield value};
{
  let [a, b, c, d] = repeat("wang");
  console.log(a, b, c, d); // "wang", "wang", "wang", "wang"
}
a; // ReferenceError
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a clever approach. Consequently I probably shan't use it in anger but it's always nice to know ;)

Comment: `function repeat(x) { while(true) yield x; }` should be abstracted into a helper function. Using a parameter has the advantage that in `let [a, b, c] = repeat({…})` all variables share the reference value, instead of copies generated in each iteration.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I thought it would be problematic if the value were an object or symbol. Using a helper function is a good idea, thanks.

Comment: Agreed, the helper function makes it much more readable, this is probably the best approach if you need to do this in more than one place or for more than a couple of variables. Thanks for updating your answer.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks again by your edit, I shouldn't attempt to fix things when I am in a hurry

Answer (score 3):

Can you try with

```
{ let [a, b] = [3, 3]; console.log(a); console.log(b)}
```

Answer (score 2):

The assignment happens from right to left. So, let statement is only applicable to `a` and not `b`

All the other variables are considered Global without the var/let statement, hence `b` will be the global